# undefined is not an object error when trying to use a component

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm trying to use  [Portal](https://medium.com/@naorzruk/portals-in-react-native-22797ba8aa1b) but i get Undefined is not an object error when i wrap my `<App/>` with the `<PortalProvider>`, basically portal lets u move a component et in the app without having to re-render it again. this is the error that i get in the app but i cant figure out why !!!

> ERROR: TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluation PortalContext>PortalContext>Provider

PortalContext.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
export default PortalContext = React.createContext({
gates: {},
teleport: (gateName: string, element: JSX.Element) => {
return
 }
})
```

PortalProvider.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { PortalContext } from './PortalContext'

interface IProps {
  children: JSX.Element
}

class PortalProvider extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public state = {
    gates: {}
  }

public render() {
const { children } = this.props
return (
  <PortalContext.Provider value={{ gates: this.state.gates, teleport: 
 this.teleport }}>
    {children}
    </PortalContext.Provider>
  )
}

 private teleport = (gateName: string, element: JSX.Element) =>
  this.setState({ gates: { ...this.state.gates, [gateName]: element } 
})
}

   export default PortalProvider
```

PortalGate.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { PortalContext } from './PortalContext'

function PortalGate(props: {
  gateName: string
  children?: (teleport: (gateName: string, element: JSX.Element) => 
void) => JSX.Element
}) {
  const { gateName, children } = props
  return (
    <PortalContext.Consumer>
      {value => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            {value.gates[gateName]}
            {children && children(value.teleport)}
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }}
    </PortalContext.Consumer>
  )
}

export default PortalGate
```

app.js

```
import * as React from 'react'
import PortalProvider from './PortalProvider'
export default class App extends React.Component{

  public render() {
    return (
      <PortalProvider>
        <App/>
      </PortalProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you're default exporting your context and using it with named import.

So, change this line:

```
import { PortalContext } from './PortalContext'
```

to:

```
import PortalContext from './PortalContext'
```

This [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for reference.

Comment: I can see several named imports, not one. did you try changing them all? also, can you copy/paste the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: it worked i didn’t  pay attention to the import in the portal gate !! thanks mate appreciate it